# #1054 - Unknown column 'Received' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  tblorder.fld_userid, tblorder.fld_first_name, 
  tblorder.fld_status, tblordereditems.fld_order_id
FROM tblorder
INNER JOIN tblordereditems ON tblorder.fld_id = tblordereditems.fld_order_id
WHERE tblorder.fld_status = Received
```

Can you tell me the error. please!
Ok i m sorry for the incomplete questions .Please dont ban be asking questions.This is only way of getting help from others.today also i have plenty of questions but i can,t ask any of them in stackoverflow.So please let me ask my question.I will be carefull from onwards.Give a warning dont just ban me.Please

Comment: -1 Comeon people this is no way to ask a question...

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html What have you tried? What have you read? What is your question?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tblorder.fld_userid, tblorder.fld_first_name, 
       tblorder.fld_status, tblordereditems.fld_order_id 
FROM tblorder 
INNER JOIN tblordereditems ON tblorder.fld_id = tblordereditems.fld_order_id
WHERE tblorder.fld_status = 'Received'
```

Comment: ok thank you very much it helps i am learning it so small  mistakes are unevitable im my query thanks